# Can we do pressing movements two days in a row

Tags: shoulders, chest, triceps

Currently I am working on Chest & biceps [ Mon ] , Triceps  [ Tue ] , Back [ Wed] , Shoulders [ Thu ], Legs  [ Fri ] from Mon to friday....

Somewhere i read below :

```
Try not to do pressing movements two days in a row. For example,
if you work Chest on Monday, work Shoulder on Wednesday, and Triceps on Friday.
```

do i need to follow above ? I am a **beginner** & also is above statement depends on **Intensity** level  ? currently i am working in **LOW** intensity ?

Comment: "I am a beginner" and you have an extra day for triceps and shoulders? Since you are already following what I'd call not exactly an optimal program, why do you care? Do whatever you like. Yes pressing movements work the same muscles, but do you use a wheelchair after leg day or do you still use your legs to walk around?

Comment: @Raditz_35 thanks , seems like there are lot of `misconceptions`  online :) , yes i have an extra day for triceps and shoulders....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frequency dictates volume.

If you train your chest once a weak you can do 15 to 20 working sets at once, if you train your chest twice you can do 7 to 10 working sets on each training day and training chest thrice means 5 to 7 sets each time.

You can train your chest in two consecutive days,as long as your volume follows a logic.

Technically if you follow Bulgarian light you could train every single day at 100% maximum intensity without problems.
It works like that 8 exercise 1 set for 1 repetition, another variation of bulgarian light includes 2 to 3 training sessions daily but this only works if you are a strength athlete and have a home gymnasium.

Another way to train daily is [greasing the groove](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rGjtPtXXWCg), but this needs a home gymnasium too.